# Vuejs Passing dynamic data from parent to child component

Tags: vue.js

I've got a view and a component. I'm trying to do auth here.

As a user, I input username and password, click `login`. This `emits` the information to the parent component, which makes a fetch request to API gateway in AWS. This fetch response has a header `X-Session-Id` that I'm interested in.

I've got the `emit` bit working fine.

However, I'm unable to pass the header value back to the component, and I'm unable to set `new_password_required` to `true`, which would add a new input field for a new password, as well as replace the `login button` with a `reset password` button.

I feel like I need to do this with props, but I'm unable to successfully pass the values from parent to child.

Also, should the reset password bit have its own component?

Here's my code below. This is my first frontend, so I'm not familiar with how I am supposed to share it (e.g. with a playground). Also, I'm trying to stick to vanilla vue for now since I'm learning (I've only get vue-router installed I think)

**parent**:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="small-container">
    <login-form @login:user="loginUser($event)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LoginForm from "@/components/LoginForm.vue";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    LoginForm
  },
  data() {
    return {
      session_id: String,
      new_password_required: Boolean
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loginUser(loginEvent) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          process.env.VUE_APP_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT + "/login/user",
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(loginEvent)
          }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        if (data.headers["X-Session-Id"] != null) {
          this.session_id = data.headers["X-Session-Id"];
          this.new_password_required = true;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
    async resetPassword(resetPasswordEvent) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          process.env.VUE_APP_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT + "/reset/user/password",
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(resetPasswordEvent)
          }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Component**:

```
<template>
  <div id="login-form">
    <h1>Serverless App</h1>
    <form>
      <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label><br />
      <input
        v-model="login_details.email_address"
        type="text"
        id="email_address"
        name="email_address"
      /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label><br />
      <input
        v-model="login_details.password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        name="password"
      />
      <label v-if="new_password_required" for="new_password"
        >New Password:</label
      ><br />
      <input
        v-if="new_password_required"
        v-model="login_details.new_password"
        type="password"
        id="new_password"
        name="new_password"
      />
    </form>
    <button v-if="!new_password_required" @click="loginUser($event)">
      Login
    </button>
    <button v-if="new_password_required" @click="resetPassword($event)">
      Reset Password
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "LoginForm",
  props: {
    session_id: String,
    new_password_required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: () => false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      login_details: {
        email_address: "",
        password: "",
        new_password: ""
      }
    };
  },

  methods: {
    loginUser() {
      console.log("testing loginUser...");
      const loginEvent = {
        email_address: this.login_details.email_address,
        password: this.login_details.password
      };
      this.$emit("login:user", loginEvent);
    },

    resetPassword() {
      console.log("testing resetPassword...");
      const resetPasswordEvent = {
        email_address: this.login_details.email_address,
        password: this.login_details.password,
        new_password: this.login_details.new_password,
        session_id: this.login_details.sessionId
      };
      this.$emit("reset:Password", resetPasswordEvent);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include why and how you intent to use `X-Session-Id` inside the child component?

Comment: of course. I'm using amazon cognito for auth. Logging in uses the Cognito `InitiateAuth()` method to see the user's status. On initial login, the status will be `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`. If no password change is needed, the user gets a bearer token.

When a password needs to be reset, another request is made to `AdminRespondToAuthChallenge()` method, which takes `X-Session-Id` as a parameter. This parameter is sent to api gateway via the `resetPassword()` method in the parent

Comment: If you add a [ref attribute to your child](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) you can access the instance method from the parent by `this.$refs.childRefName.resetPassword(sessionId)`. That is one way of doing it, probably easiest way.

Comment: when do you want to set new_password_required to true?

Comment: @Amaarrockz I figured it out, see answer below. I wanted to set `new_password_required` to true if the parent's `loginUser()` fetch response had `X-Session-Id` in the headers. This header gets returned by my backend golang lambda if the backend's request to aws cognito `InitiateAuth()` method responds telling me to reset the password for the user (which requires a session-id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child component looks good, however, you need to pass the props through in the parent component as shown here:

```html
<login-form @login:user="loginUser($event)" :session-id="xidhere"
    :new-password-required="newPasswordRequired"/>
```

As these values are updated in the parent component, the child component should be updated.

As a note, name your props using camel case, and then use kebab-case in your HTML.

So your login-form props should be updated to:

```js
  props: {
    sessionId: String,
    newPasswordRequired: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: () => false
    }
  },
```

Also, as you are emitting the event to parent, there may be no need to send the session id to the child, just add this to your api call before you send it.

Comment: Cheers. Haven't quite nailed the CamelCase here kebab-case there bits. I know it's a thing but it's been de-prioritized ha. This is a better solution than what I've come up with as well as there's only one component and therefore less duplication. Dunno how making a separate component magically caused me to figure out the that I need to send the prop to the child with `:new-password`

Comment: Good work. Little by little you will get there!  Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I created a new child component for resetting password. Perhaps it can be dry'd up a bit? I'm new at this. Happy for any pointers :)

**PARENT**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="small-container">
    <login-form v-if="!new_password_required" @login:user="loginUser($event)" />
    <reset-password-form
      v-if="new_password_required"
      :session_id="session_id"
      @reset:password="resetPassword($event)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LoginForm from "@/components/LoginForm.vue";
import ResetPasswordForm from "@/components/ResetPasswordForm.vue";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    LoginForm,
    ResetPasswordForm
  },
  data() {
    return {
      session_id: "",
      new_password_required: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loginUser(loginEvent) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          process.env.VUE_APP_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT + "/login/user",
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(loginEvent)
          }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        if (data.headers["X-Session-Id"] != null) {
          this.session_id = data.headers["X-Session-Id"];
          this.new_password_required = true;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },

    async resetPassword(resetPasswordEvent) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          process.env.VUE_APP_API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT + "/reset/user/password",
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(resetPasswordEvent)
          }
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**CHILD: login-form**

```
<template>
  <div id="login-form">
    <h1>Serverless Release Dashboard</h1>
    <form>
      <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label><br />
      <input
        v-model="login_details.email_address"
        type="text"
        id="email_address"
        name="email_address"
      /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label><br />
      <input
        v-model="login_details.password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        name="password"
      />
    </form>
    <button @click="loginUser($event)">
      Login
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "LoginForm",
  data() {
    return {
      login_details: {
        email_address: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };
  },

  methods: {
    loginUser() {
      console.log("testing loginUser...");
      const loginEvent = {
        email_address: this.login_details.email_address,
        password: this.login_details.password
      };
      this.$emit("login:user", loginEvent);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**CHILD: reset-password-form**

```
<template>
  <div id="reset-password-form">
    <h1>Serverless Release Dashboard</h1>
    <form>
      <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label><br />
      <input
        v-model="login_details.email_address"
        type="text"
        id="email_address"
        name="email_address"
      /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label><br />
      <input
        v-model="login_details.password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        name="password"
      />
      <label for="new_password">New Password:</label><br />
      <input
        v-model="login_details.new_password"
        type="password"
        id="new_password"
        name="new_password"
      />
    </form>
    <button @click="resetPassword($event)">
      Reset Password
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ResetPasswordForm",

  props: {
    email_address: String,
    password: String,
    session_id: String
  },

  data() {
    return {
      login_details: {
        email_address: "",
        password: "",
        new_password: "",
        session_id: ""
      }
    };
  },

  methods: {
    resetPassword() {
      console.log("testing resetPassword...");

      const loginEvent = {
        email_address: this.email_address,
        password: this.password,
        new_password: this.login_details.new_password,
        session_id: this.session_id
      };
      this.$emit("reset:password", loginEvent);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```